# reproducible random sequences for multithreaded C pthreads simulator

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads

I'm working on a [Wa-tor](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor) simulator in C with very strict requirements and I'm a little confused on how to properly get reproducible behaviour between calls with the same arguments.

Wa-tor is basically a 2D array of cells that can contain water only, a fish or a shark.

What I have is (i'll try to list only what's interesting to understand the problem):

- a configuration file, where the user can specify an integer seed, among other options
- a master process, that parse the configuration file and spawns (fork+execve) as many worker subprocess as requested by the user. Further it will collect the status from all the workers displaying it as a single big grid. Workers communicate with master through a UNIX socket file.
- many multithreaded (pthreads) worker process.

Workers connect to master socket and receive simulation parameters, included seed as specified by the user (at the moment the seed is differentiated between workers adding the worker ID to it. Worker ID is a progressive number that the master reproducibly assigns to the worker and is included on the command line on execve, so the worker can identify upon connection to master's socket and each time be assigned to the same grid section).

Worker randomly initialize its subgrid sending it to the master, then receive/send the border values from/to adjacent workers.

Worker's state from now on evolves in discrete steps called chronon. In each step the worker calculate a random action for each creature of its subgrid, then exchanges the updates with adjacent worker and with master.

One thread listen for signals, while another routine handles the "simulation" part. This simulation routine -at the end of each step- spawn 4 other threads to send updates to adjacent threads, 4 to receive updates, 1 to send status to master. This threads are hereafter joined before starting another step.

What I'm doing at the moment to handle the generation of random numbers is to have a global "unsigned int SEED", that is provided with the value received from the master at the beginning of the worker process (before any thread is spawned), and included in every file where I need it using the "extern" keyword. So I use its address on calls to "rand_r(&SEED)".

The first problem is that the value of SEED is not updated after calls to rand_r, as instead I can observe running a single threaded application. What am I forgetting?

Then I'm asking if a global variable is a correct way of doing to get reproducible sequences admitting that rand_r could be called by different threads, and that the sequences of actions could change as the communication between workers doesn't follow a strict order, -and if not what could be such way, starting from a single integer value as seed? Requirements are that, starting with the same exact parameters and seed, two executions produces the same results step after step (like any respectable simulator, i guess :)

P.s. I'm thinking of switching to drand48_r() but the soup is the same, i guess.

Regards
DR

Comment: SioulSeuguh gives you the right idea, I think. But your idea to switch to the `drand48` family in addition is certainly a good idea, too. You don't need `_r`, here, `erand48`, `jrand48` and `nrand48` are versions that receive the state as an argument.

Comment: @SioulSeuguh Reading both the manuals for [e,j,n]rand48 and the respective _r reentrant versions, i can't be totally sure that the non-reentrant ones do not use a global random generator state. The man says that the `unsigned short xsubi[3]` taken by non-reentrant functions serves as "storage for the successive Xi values",but I think that other values stored in the global state are used to calculate the random value.In addiction the man for the _r versions specifically says that "Instead of modifying the global random generator state,they use the supplied data buffer" a `struct drand48_data *`

Answer (score 3):

By having a single global var SEED , the behavior of rand_r is not thread safe  - it would be thread safe if there were a seed var per thread. I would suggest to generate  a distinct seed per thread with rand_r from your initial SEED at init time. Then each thread runs independently with its own same random sequence.